# Parse Push: Which is the preferred way to uniquely identify a device: installationId or deviceToken?

Tags: android, parse-platform

When sending a push to a single device, which is the preferred way to identify that device?

**deviceToken**

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().get("deviceToken");
```

**installationId**

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId()
```

Are there tradeoffs between the two? Will one be available sooner than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the id rather than the device token. The device token could be in different formats depending on the platform (iOS or Android) and the id is (assumed to be) a primary key for the installations table, so might be a bit faster.

In either case, you specify the target of a push by using either a query or a channel name, so in your case, it's how you create the installation query to use on the `setQuery` method of the ParsePush object.