# Database creation for web + android app?

Tags: javascript, html, database, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm trying to create an app for teachers in my college from which a teacher just can select students which are present from list and once the list is submitted every app should be updated with the attendance list how can i create this kind of database for my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is using php server files with android app.As in your scenario you can create two modules teachers and students module. For teachers As far as selection is concerned you can use dynamic check box and and a status(present/absent) field in your table such that if checkbox is selected then status is present or absent and maintain one count variable to count the attendance based on date field.
For students module retrieve the status field and display it based on dates.

Comment: I have created the front end I'm just stuck at how the database containing attendance will be updated in every app I can locally store it but will not be showed in every app.

Comment: you can fire cron notification whenever the database is updated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957840/sending-push-notifications-to-a-targeted-device

Comment: Apology.... It's not Cron it's curl

Comment: I have been using phpMyadmin mysql for creating databases on Localhost I have never done anything on actual server. How will i connect my apps to single database?

Comment: I know its kinda of trivial question to ask but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are going in right direction just don't worry about actual server ,if you want to deploy you can deploy to the actual server as well ,use free hosting sites such as 000webhost .

Comment: I can provide you the hint. Suppose you have a Android app which has a form with textboxes ,checkboxes ....  you have to collect the data from the from the activity xml files and store those values inside string variables and pass those values using namevalue pairs or any other...and send the values from string variables to a php file which will receive the values and perform insert query and boom your data is inserted

Comment: And then I will just have to place those php files on actual server and then just give the server address instead of localhost, right?

Comment: One more hint is with your confusion with app and apps..   it's just. App->Phpfile->db  db->Phpfile->App

Comment: Ya.. it's correct.. :)

Comment: Pleasure .. Get it done .. :) Good luck